# Android foreach loop with object class

Tags: android, json, foreach

I have a class called `CarData[]` (with `setters` and `getters`). I want to create a list with a `recyclerView` using my `Json` parsed data. I want to use a **`foreach loop`** but I don't know how to do it.

For now, I get a duplicate of a first item. I believe using a **loop** I will not get duplicated data.

Comment: You can create an ArrayList of your class instead using it like CarData[]. It will make your life easier

Comment: ArrayList<CarData> dataSet=new Array<>();

For each:-

for (CarData carData:dataSet){ // Your Code}.

You can also it pass it to your CustomAdapter. To fill up the views with data.

Comment: If you want to avoid duplication without checking, use a stack instead and use .pop()

Comment: Please show a [mcve]  with what you have tried.  Also show any errors  you get.

Answer (score 2):

If you have list of Car objects inside a List, sample for foeach loop is

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
for (Cars car : cars) {
    // get each car object on the list
}
```

But this does not prevent duplication. you can compare some features of car objects you get from JSON file.